# trasformation matrix for model's bones

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, fbx

I was developing an fbx converter for legend of grimrock object model ([www.grimrock.net](http://www.grimrock.net)), I just wanted to get the animations cause the rest has been converted by others' tools.
I was reading all of their guidelines to convert from their little endian binary file to the format I want (in this case fbx)
When I was about to construct the skeleton, I was stuck because of this

```
// A Mat4x3 is a transformation matrix split into 3x3 rotation and 3D rotation parts
struct Mat4x3
{
    Vec3    baseX;
    Vec3    baseY;
    Vec3    baseZ;
    Vec3    translation;
}
```

(btw Vec3 is a three dimensional vector (xyz) you can find complete specifications of their object model [here](http://www.grimrock.net/modding_log1/model-and-animation-file-formats/))

what does "A Mat4x3 is a transformation matrix split into 3x3 rotation and 3D rotation parts" mean????
Regarding the creation of bones, I thoughtmatrix should be a transformation matrix not a rotation matrix.
So I'm kinda confused.
Anyway I should calculate this way? (o = origin)

```
x' = x*x1 + y*y1 + z*z1 + o1;
y' = x*x2 + y*y2 + z*z2 + o2;
z' = x*x3 + y*y3 + z*z3 + o3;
```

Comment: Why not asking them what they mean by it?

Comment: Well they simply didn't give any help and they didn't answer. Private messages on the forum to the developers is not permitted.. I'm getting crazy lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have conflicting comments and code, either one or both of them are incorrect.

In this case, it seems likely that the `3D rotation` in the comment is supposed to be a `3D translation`.

In general, a 4x3 transformation matrix is like a regular 4x4 transformation matrix, but the fourth part with `[0 0 0 1]` is omitted for saving space and work.

Comment: thank you!!! unfortunately I'm not so great at linear algebra so I'm finding a way to get this sorted out, that comment was misleading I guess.